# Multiple MountPoints creation and change default username in ICECAST

Tags: audio-streaming, icecast

I have an icecast server setup and streaming fine however I now need to have multiple mount points configured on the icecast server end not the client so I can control mountpoint names, password, usernames for login onto the icecast server.

I know that by default mount points are configure at the client side via their client audio source software e.g. Mixxx, virtual DJ, BuTT, etc when not specified in the icecast server and this is displayed on the server status page when you connect via the web interface see image:

[image: icecast reconfigured and mount point via BuTT]

Now the advanced part. I'm having issues understanding the mount point configuration in the XML file: where it starts and stops, what is remarked and what is code. I am no coder but can understand some parts of it.

This is the advanced part, not the default source and stream username and password it configuring this for yourself and not using the default.

[image: default mount point code section unedited]

This is the default mount point code which you need to edit in order to create multiple mount points, so for now I just want to edit and create one and I do the rest once I understand it more.

### Summary

I need assistance with advanced configuration of mount point on icecast server which then you give to the client and they cannot connect to the icecast server unless they have this info. I also want to change the default username from source as I know how to change the logon password.

### Setup info if needed

Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V core with Icecast running on a VM and ports open via router. To see demo site currently live streaming go to [my test site](http://www.fabtabulousfm.uk).

Comment: Since the answer to this was "I edited a few things", I think this ought to be closed, since it is unlikely to be useful to future readers. From the official close reasons: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: In any case, we prefer XML and other text-based config to be supplied as text, not images.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out in the XML under mount points, there are a few things to edit and comment out so the don't initialise during or before streaming.

If not do this when you try to stream you get a login page which all users including the DJ have to enter a user name and password. Managed to figure it out, and now it's all working.